# Backup linux workstation command

Tags: linux, backup, centos, restore

So I'm what you'll call a "almost" noob when it comes to linux. I recently started working on a CentOS workstation and I know there's a lot of customizations on it from the other user. I also know there's a ton of updates (like 800) that I itch to install. What directories do I need to backup and how, to ensure that this shared work PC will be able to restore to its previous condition, should this backup process break a ton of stuff? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to take a image of the partition/hard drive. Take a look at 
[dd man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html). 
[dd @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).
[some dd commands](https://blog.kintoandar.com/2010/02/how-to-disk-dump-dd.html)

In short, you use dd to take a image of your partition/harddrive with command 
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/backupfoler/sda.img
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/backupfolder/sda1.img`
and to restore, you just boot the computer with a live cd and reverse the if= and of=. dd is almost always installed in every linux system/live-cd

```
dd if=/path/to/image/sda.img of=/dev/sda
dd if=/path/to/image/sda1.img of=/dev/sda1
```

Just check with `fdisk -l` to se what hard drive/partition you need to take an image of.

alternatively take a look at dump tool.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I decided to go ahead and update without backup, I don't have enough HDD for a full image.. Fingers crossed it won't break my system! Thank you for the time though!

Comment: @drobalqk No need to try if you don’t have the space. Also, taking a backup of a mounted filesystem this way isn’t a good idea, because it’s not clean.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I see. But you should at least take a backup of
/home <- user files
/etc <- this is where the configuration files are located.
/var
with "tar" you could archive those dirs like this.

```
tar -pcvzf backup.tar.gz /home /etc /var --exclude='/var/tmp' --exclude='/var/lock'
```

`--exclude='/var/run'`

You could check the size of those directories and se if you have space for it with "du"

```
du -h -c /home | grep total
du -h -c /etc | grep total
du -h -c /var | grep total
```

This backup should get you covered for most. You just have too reinstall the system/softwares if it bricks.

Comment: You also need to consider /usr/local, /opt, /root.   You might be better off making a separate tar file for each top level directory so you can restore parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up does not break anything.

To get an exact duplicate of the system, doing a bit copy of the drive (maybe compressing it first) is the way to go.   I understand you don't want to do that, which means you will be making some compromises.

- From a users perspective /home/*  is probably the most important, and
  similarly /root
- /etc contains your system configuration settings and is particularly useful.
- Depending on what you install /opt may be vital or totally unimportant and not even exist.  Similarly /usr/local
- Parts of /var may be useful as well, but you can probably leave out much of it, including /var/log, /var/cache, /var/spool  - Note that a lot of databases (mysql, postgres) install under /var by default.  You might be better off dumping these to SQL.
  If you have "extra" disks, you may need to look at /media - but this is unlikely to form a core part of your system.

If you have a "vanilla" install and have only used standard packages, you probably don't need to back up /usr - but you should do a rpm -qa > /root/files.lst  - This will dump a list of the installed packages - you will want this list so you can ensure all the packages are installed on your new system if you need to go there.